# PHP echo inside input dont work?

Tags: php, input, echo, space

```
<input name="name" type="text"  
       id="nome" size="45"  maxlength="35" value=<?php echo "need help" ?>/>
```

// output "need"
but i expect  "need help"

it was a POST var string of a name, but just out puts the fist name, then i realised the echo or print do not work with whitespace inside the tag value, like echo do outside

what the solution to  "need help"??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Currently, your HTML mark up would look like:

```
<input name="name" type="text"  
           id="nome" size="45"  maxlength="35" value=need help/> 
                                               ^--------^
```

As it's evident from the  syntax highlighting here, only `need` is considered as part of the `value` attribute. `help` is being considered as a separate new attribute.

You need quotes around the attribute value:

```
<input name="name" type="text"  
       id="nome" size="45"  maxlength="35" value="<?php echo "need help" ?>"/> 
                                                 ^                         ^
```

Comment: i agree with this.. and you should take a look at some Templates like **[Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)** because coding like this isnt very nice :)

Comment: Yeah,mix html and php in a same file just make you dizzy

Comment: THANK YOU, it works, i lose very time whit this, and was so simple.. may solution was converting a php variable (with 2 words) in a Javascript variable, a put it in the form with document.getelementbyid.. on body action onload, thank you a

Comment: Like the `^--------^` notation. Using it makes everything clear, in a second.

Comment: @hek2mgl: I agree. It helps highlight the part where the code's been changed :)

Answer (score 1):

try this code.

```
<input name="name" type="text"  
       id="nome" size="45"  maxlength="35" value="<?php echo 'need help'; ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In MVC you can do something like this

```
<input name="name" type="text"  
       id="nome" size="45"  maxlength="35" value="{{$person->island}}"/>
```